# IOS emulator app stay in background

Tags: react-native

I have a problem when running `react-native run-ios` on my project.

The IOS emulator launch well.
Then the application start (react-native white splash screen) and immediately after that, it return me to the Iphone home screen.

If I `Cmd-Shift-H` (with pressing H two times) I saw the app in the background (still with the react-native white splash screen). 
When I click on it, it return me to the home screen again.

If I launch the Xcode project and run the app, it work fine and I can navigate in my application.

I've had some troubles with my app before, the IOS version was 'abandoned' and I've installed a lot of modules and changed the name of the project in the mean time, before trying to make it work on IOS. 
Then I've decided to create a new project with `react-native init myNewProject` (because I couldn't figured out how to fix the IOS, something with a workspace not configured) and copy paste my old `src` and `index.ios/android.js` inside.

So now Android is still working and IOS is only working if I launch the app from Xcode.

I've tried to reset the emulator but it don't change anything.
I don't have any logs about app crash or something.
The Android app version is working fine.

Any idea ?

#### Logs

I've put the device logs after running `react-native run-ios` on a gist
https://gist.github.com/ansmonjol/f6fa1e71a20b944bf67429c57d081165

#### Additional Information

- React Native version: 0.35
- Platform: IOS
- Operating System: macOS El capitan
- Xcode: Version 8.0

Comment: Didn't found any solution. I've finally created a new project, imported all my code inside and re-installed all my packages following all install config

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, and solve it:
In my case i install third-party native component in my project and link it using command `react-native link <component-name>`. Than i have a problem about you wrote:

Running project by Xcode - works fine. Bundling start, after loading dependency graph.
But runnig project by `react-native run-ios` app hide immediately and bundling not started after loading dependency graph. And not any errors happened.

I tried reinstall all, clean npm cache, react-native upgrade, delete build folder, delete derived data... nothing helped.

I found one way that helped me:
I remove that problem library **not manyally from Xcode**, **but from terminal using command** `react-native unlink <component-name>`. Its way to resolve this problem for me, maybe for you too.

Sorry for my english.